# MCP604 op-amp output seems to jump to the positive rail

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm hoping someone can give me some insight as to what's going wrong with this [MCP604 op-amp](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21314g.pdf).  I'm seeing this issue on about 150 of the ICs.  Below are some specs for the MCP604 and an image from my oscilloscope.

The yellow line is from the V+ of the op-amp, and the pink is Vout. It looks like the output is jumping up the positive rail.  Is this a defective part?

My input signal is 0 - 3.3 V and it's passing through a 10k resistor.  I have a 0.1 uF cap right next to the power connection.  Anyone have an idea of what's going on?

[image: screenshot from datasheet]

[image: Yellow: Vi+ Pink: Vout]

Comment: Welcome to SE EE. Your problem could be **perfectly normal** depending on **how you're using the opamp**. Show us your **schematic** and tell us what you're trying to achieve. As it is we can only guess and say "Maybe you're using it wrong?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be running afoul of the upper-end of the common-mode range, which is 1.2V below the Vdd rail:
[image: snippet of MCP604 data sheet]

Recovery from this condition is often slow for high-gain op-amps.

Comment: Yup.  That would be it.  Crappy.  Will exceeding the common mode range damage the opamp?

Comment: Damage is defined by the specs in the **Absolute Maximum Ratings** (included in the OP). That upper 1.2V region just yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank-you very much for the information.  Obviously I need to spend more time reading stack Exchange.

Comment: those opamps may use only PCHANNEL input diffpair FETS. FInd a rail-rail input rail-rail output opamp.